# Remove manually using str_replace or other

Tags: php

Can anybody help me to make this code using `str_replace` or other method will be fine.

```
$data = 'a:2:{i:0;s:2:"67";i:1;s:2:"64";}';
```

into

```
$data = 'a:1:{i:0;s:2:"67";}';<br>
```

because there is a number 64 in it.
What is the code then?

Answer (score 2):

Simply use [`serialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php),[`unserialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) and [`unset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) function of PHP instead of [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
$data = 'a:2:{i:0;s:2:"67";i:1;s:2:"64";}';
$data = unserialize($data);
unset($data[1]);
echo serialize($data);
```

Comment: Thanks Uchika. That is working. But I have another question and I know I should ask this earlier. If I want to change that value because there is a number 64 in it, what is the code?

Comment: What value you need to change it over here

Comment: some thing like : if there is a number 64 in a:2:{i:0;s:2:"67";i:1;s:2:"64";} then it will be change to a:1:{i:0;s:2:"67";}.